# For a result set of N rows, populate a certain column value only for the first row in these N rows when using SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL query in SQL Server 2014 as shown below. My problem is that the column of `TotalRecordsCount` is being returned for each and every row in the returned result set.

I would like to populate the column `TotalRecordsCount` only for first row in the result set. So, if the result set has 10 rows and TotalRecordsCount is 5000, then only the first row will have a value of 5000 for this column and all the other rows will have a null value for this column.

**Question** : How would I do this using the query below?

```
WITH x AS 
( 
           SELECT     u.UserId, 
                      u.UserName, 
                      u.Email, 
                      u.Firstname + isnull(' ' + u.Lastname, '') userfullname, 
                      u.Activated, 
                      [dbo].[xyz_fn_getUserRoles](u.userid) VendorUserRoles 
           FROM       dbo.Users U 
           INNER JOIN dbo.SupplierUsers su 
           ON         u.UserId = su.UserId 
           WHERE      su.SupplierId = @SupplierId 
           AND        u.UserName IS NOT NULL ), 
          TotalRecords AS (SELECT Count(UserId) TotalRecordsCount FROM x) 
SELECT x.UserId, 
       x.UserName, 
       x.Email, 
       x.UserFullName, 
       x.Activated, 
       x.UserRoles, 
       TotalRecordsCount 
FROM   x OFFSET @startRowIndex rows FETCH next @maximumRows rows only;
```

Comment: The best way is to worry about display in the UI layer of your application and not in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the final `select` after the cte's with one more `select` to show Totalrecords only on the first row in the resultset based on a specified order. (I assume the `order by` is for userid's, if not you should change it.)

Also, you were not joining the `TotalRecords` cte. The query in question would result in an error.The query below fixes it with a `cross join`.

```
WITH x AS 
(SELECT     u.UserId, 
                      u.UserName, 
                      u.Email, 
                      u.Firstname + isnull(' ' + u.Lastname, '') userfullname, 
                      u.Activated, 
                      [dbo].[xyz_fn_getUserRoles](u.userid) VendorUserRoles 
           FROM       dbo.Users U 
           INNER JOIN dbo.SupplierUsers su 
           ON         u.UserId = su.UserId 
           WHERE      su.SupplierId = @SupplierId 
           AND        u.UserName IS NOT NULL ), 
          TotalRecords AS (SELECT Count(UserId) TotalRecordsCount FROM x) 
SELECT t1.*, 
case when row_number() over(order by t1.UserID) = 1 then t2.TotalRecordsCount end 
as TotalRecordsCount
FROM (
SELECT x.UserId, 
       x.UserName, 
       x.Email, 
       x.UserFullName, 
       x.Activated, 
       x.UserRoles
FROM   x OFFSET @startRowIndex rows FETCH next @maximumRows rows only
) t1 
CROSS JOIN TotalRecords t2;
```